# Gorp Insertion with an embedded struct

Tags: go, gorp

I am new to Gorp and golang.

https://github.com/go-gorp/gorp

I have a mysql table like

```
Table: product

Column: id(int), name(string), category1(string), category2(string)
```

and I created an embedded struct like

```
type (
    Product struct {
        Id       int
        Name     Names `db:"name"`
        Categories Categories

    }

    Categories struct {
        Category1 string `db:"category1"`
        Category2 string `db:"category2"`
    }
)
```

And I executed the following script

```
.......
product := &Product{-1,"foobar", Categories{"sample1", "sample2"}}
err := dbmap.Insert(product)
fmt.Println(err)
```

But I got this error message below

```
converting Exec argument $2 type: unsupported type main.Categories, a struct
```

I thought I had followed the manual of Struct Embedding.

https://github.com/go-gorp/gorp#struct-embedding

Please help me understand why I am still getting this error.

Comment: Where `Names` is defined ? Apparently in your case you only need a `string`

Comment: You likely want  Name     string `db:"name"`

Comment: Sorry I put a previous error, the correct one is
   "
converting Exec argument $2 type: unsupported type main. **Categories** , a struct
   " 
(I changed the database scheme )